# Trying to assign a 1 dimensional array from an arraylist to another variable

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So I have an arraylist whose elements are 1 dimensional arrays, and I am trying to access that arraylist, and save it's first element on another variable, using the following piece of code, but the compiler gives me an "incopatible types, Object cannot be converted to int" error

```
int[] k=new int[3];
k[0]=0;
k[1]=0;
k[2]=0;
ArrayList qu=new ArrayList();
qu.add(0,k);
int[] j=new int[3];
j= qu.get(0);
```

Comment: You might want to specify the generic type of the `ArrayList`, e.g. `ArrayList<int[]>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using generics, do an explicit cast

```
j= (int[]) qu.get(0);
```

or you can use generics. Notice that arrays are objects in java and hence can be used as type parameters.

```
ArrayList<int[]> qu=new ArrayList<int[]>();
qu.add(0,k);
int[] j=new int[3];
j= qu.get(0);
```